# How to from one field Textarea add a some lines to the database?

Tags: php

I have a one textarea field. How when adding to the database, take into account the transfer and, accordingly, add a new line to the database?

Sample:

[img textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dm5n.png)
and [img result in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQxr2.png)

```
<?
$data = $_POST;

if ( isset($data['add']) )
{
$post = R::dispense('users');
$post->title = $data['title']; // textarea field

R::store($post);
}
?>

<form action="/" method="POST">
<textarea name="title"></textarea>
<button name="add" type="submit">Add</button>
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: @MarkOverton Changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should split up the textarea value by new lines, creating an array for each of the text on different lines, we can then loop through this array and insert each line as a new row.

```
$data = $_POST;

if (isset($data['add'])) {

    $results = explode("\r\n", $data['title']);

    foreach($results as $result) {

        // Run your insert code here.
        $post = R::dispense('users');
        $post->title = $result;

        R::store($post);
    }

}
```